# Is It Possible to Set a std::function out of Class which need to Access private class member in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm writing a Priority Queue, here is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <functional>

template <class T>
class MaxPQ
{
public:
    MaxPQ(size_t size): container(size)
    {
    }

    MaxPQ(std::vector<T>& Raw)
    {
        //hard-code set it inside of class
        //this->setWrapper([=](size_t x, size_t y) -> bool { return this->container[x] < this->container[y]; });

        container.clear();
        for (const auto& val : Raw)
        {
            this->insert(val);
        }
    }

    MaxPQ(): container(0)
    {
    }

    ~MaxPQ()
    {
        container.clear();
    }

    void setWrapper(std::function<bool(size_t, size_t)> input)
    {
        compare_wrapper = input;
    }

    void insert(T newEle)
    {
        container.push_back(newEle);
        swim(container.size() - 1);
    }

    T delMax()
    {
        T result = max();
        swapByIndex(0, container.size() - 1);
        container.erase(container.end());
        sink(0);
        return result;
    }

    inline T max()
    {
        return container[0];
    }

    void swapByIndex(size_t Left, size_t Right)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(container[Left], container[Right]);
    }


    inline size_t left(size_t parent)
    {
        return parent * 2 + 1;
    }

    inline size_t right(size_t parent)
    {
        return parent * 2 + 2;
    }

    inline size_t parent(size_t child)
    {
        return (child - 1) >= 0 ? (child - 1) / 2 : -1;
    }

    void print()
    {
        using std::cout;
        for (const auto& val : container)
            cout << val << " ";
        cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> container;
    std::function<bool(size_t, size_t)> compare_wrapper;

    void swim(size_t targetIndex)
    {
        while (targetIndex > 0 && compare_wrapper(parent(targetIndex), targetIndex))
        {
            swapByIndex(parent(targetIndex), targetIndex);
            targetIndex = parent(targetIndex);
        }
    }

    void sink(size_t targetIndex)
    {
        while (left(targetIndex) < container.size())
        {
            size_t maxIndex = left(targetIndex);
            if (right(targetIndex) < container.size() && compare_wrapper(maxIndex, right(targetIndex)))
            {
                maxIndex = right(targetIndex);
            }
            if (compare_wrapper(maxIndex, targetIndex))
            {
                break;
            }
            swapByIndex(targetIndex, maxIndex);
            targetIndex = maxIndex;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> temp{1, 8, 0, 9, 12, 4};
    auto myPQ = new MaxPQ<int>(temp);
    myPQ->setWrapper([=](size_t x, size_t y) -> bool
    {
//error here, trying to access private member `container`
        return myPQ->container[x] < myPQ->container[y];
    }); //set it out of class
    myPQ->print();
}
```

all code works pretty fine when I hard-code `compare` to `bool less(int,int)()`
`bool less(int,int)()` is a private (because there is no need to let other call it) member function which will access private member `container`
but others may want to custom the function
I guess it looks like a function come from outside, but can act like a member function (which could access private member)

so How could I do so(to set such wrapper function by using lambda function or std::function), where should I write the setWrapper funtion, and where should I call it

is this a good design?

how does std::for_each set its function wrapper?

I'm new to STL, I may have some term or concept wrong, and English is not my first language, please forgive me.

thanks in advance

Comment: I can't help but think that your [mre] isn't really that *minimal*. There's a lot of things in there that is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: I also wonder why you have used a pointer for `myPQ`? Do you perhaps come from Java or C#, where object must be created with `new`? C++ is *very* different than those languages, and you should rarely need to use `new` or pointers.

Comment: Does your comparator have to take indexes or could it just use the elements instead? Then you'd avoid the need to access the private data

Comment: One flaw of your design in its current state is that several methods of the class depend on the instantiation of the comparison function. I would advise to enforce the comparison function to be passed as parameter to the constructors (and maybe have a default comparison function).

Comment: Side note: member functions defined inside the class are implicitly `inline`. There is no need to add `inline` to declare `left` for example, as `swapByIndex` is also `inline`. I guess you misunderstood when the keyword is doing: it is only used to avoid ODR (one definition rule) problems, **not** for code inlining.

Comment: This is a bug: `(child - 1) >= 0`. Variable `child` is of type `size_t`, so `unsigned`. Therefore `child - 1` is still unsigned and is always `>=0`. You want to write `child > 0` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it if you change compare signature to compare value instead.

```cpp
template <class T>
class MaxPQ
{
public:

    using compare_func_type = std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)>; //use this instead of your old std::function<bool(size_t, size_t)>
...
}
```

If you really need it. You can use [Friend declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) with function for create your lambda.

```cpp
template <class T>
class MaxPQ
{
public:

    template<typename V>
    friend std::function<bool(size_t, size_t)> create_compare(const MaxPQ<V>& myPQ);
...
}

template<typename V>
std::function<bool(size_t, size_t)> create_compare(const MaxPQ<V>& myPQ)
{
    return [=](size_t x, size_t y) -> bool //this line have problem because we capture by copy if there is some change in source element  after capture. it should cause undefined behavior.
    {
        return myPQ.container[x] < myPQ.container[y];
    };
}

int main()
{
   ...
   auto myPQ = new MaxPQ<int>(temp);
   myPQ->setWrapper(create_compare(*myPQ));
   ...
}
```

Comment: Your `create_compare` is *dangerous*, you capture by copy, so compare element of a snapshot. Capturing by reference would also be problematic for copy of `MaxPQ`...

Comment: @Jarod42 I saw many thing in KSroido 's code need to be improve. 
But to make my answer in scope of his question, I try don't change his code so much. I hope he use my first method.

Answer (score 1):

The data you want to access is private so inaccessible inside of your lambda.

One of the way you could achieve this is making it a member function instead of your lambda. Of course that would change the signature unless you use bind (or anything similar)